# Как реагирует js на щелчок по конкретному MathML-элементу?

Tags: javascript

Большая просьба к спецам в js помочь. Допустим с XHTML все понятно: есть скажем список элементов, каждый из которых может реагировать на событие onclick! А как это реализовано в MathML непонятно, такое ощущение, что этот onclick с MathML вообще не работает!

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен на 100% в своей правоте, но HTML(XHTML) и MathML оба являясь приложениями xml, преследуют разные цели - HTML(XHTML) языки разметки интерпретируемые браузерами в человеко-удобную форму, где JavaScript исполняется браузером и оперирует с DOM, в то время как MathML - предназначен для хранения структурированных данных, так же как и XML. Оперировать с ними JavaScript не будет, хотя бы потому, что структура объектной модели другая.
Вот пара ссылок:

1. [XHTML](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML)
2. [DOM](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM)
3. [XML](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)